# can 2 3mm leds fit within a 5mm bi-color led without bending wires?

Tags: led, pcb, pcb-design, pcb-fabrication

After creating a circuit calling for a bi-color common-anode LED, I checked places for stock, and to my dismay, all they wanted to sell common-cathode bi-color LED, but the funny thing is I can order either common-anode or common-cathode RGB LED.

So my question is, since I created a physical PCB, etched and all with holes drilled ready for a common-anode bi-color LED, I will need alternatives. Would I somehow be able to squeeze in two 3mm LEDs or something to achieve similar output without having to redo the whole PCB?

I mean sure, I could hang LEDs off long wires, but that's less professional.

Are there any other suggestions? I mean I could look for the part on ebay and pray I can find it, but are there any other ideas other than what I mentioned?

Comment: Where have you been looking? Digikey has a number of bi-color CA 5mm LEDs.

Comment: As does Mouser, and I expect a wide variety of other distributors.

Comment: Eg.  Marktech Optoelectronics MT6224-AHRG-A  $0.1422 USD/1K 7,600+ in stock. That's red/green, there may be other color combinations available.

Comment: Less professional than not finalizing your BOM before making PCBs ... ?

Comment: what's wrong with the RGB ones? (certainly better than cramming)

Comment: How much space do you need between the PCB and LED base? How much space around that LED is available?

Answer (score 2):

Depending on how much space you have between the base of the LEDs and the PCB, and the quantity of LEDs you will have to do this, you can wrap the anode of one LED in the anode of the other and solder them, to make only one anode leg. See the picture bellow.

[image]

But if you're going to make a lot of these (I believe not. Greater quantities usually means a good supplier), this method may be too much time and money consuming.

Comment: Thats the idea I have but I guess I have no choice but to make the LEDs raised somewhat?

Answer (score 1):

Use the 5mm RGB LED. As you say they are available to order.
RGB LEDs have 4 legs, you need just 3, so you can snip one of them (of course the leg you do not need).

Comment: That's a bit of a cash waste. Locally RGB LEDs go for $1.25+ each where as a bi-color LED I can get 2 for $1.50.

Comment: @mike of course a RGB LED costs more than a 2-color LED. But you made mistake and are looking for workaround. Some solution costs more but will look perfectly, and some is cheap and will look cheap. It's up to you. You are the one who made mistake, you have to choose solution you prefer.